# Returning a single type from a union return type determined by a parameter value

Tags: typescript

I have the following Typescript code:

```js
type Encoding = 'binary' | 'utf8';
type EncodingType = { binary: string, utf8: Uint8Array };

interface FS {
  readFile: <T extends Encoding>(path: string, opts?: { encoding?: T, flags?: string }) => EncodingType[T];
}

type FSMethodNames = { [K in keyof FS]: (FS)[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never }[keyof FS];
type FSMethodArgs = { [K in FSMethodNames]: Parameters<FS[K]> };
type FSMethodReturn = { [K in FSMethodNames]: ReturnType<FS[K]> };

FS<Method extends FSMethodNames>(method: Method, ...args: FSMethodArgs[Method]): FSMethodReturn[Method];
```

I am attempting to return a single type from the `readFile` function depending on the provided value for `encoding`, which is either `string` or `utf8`. As of now it is always returning `string | Uint8Array`.

This is in a typescript `index.d.ts` to add typings to preexisting JS code.

Example call:

```js
import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';

const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg();
const video: File;

await ffmpeg.load();

// Get video from user...

// Write the file 
ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'video', fetchFile(video));

// Misc. FFmpeg code to convert to gif...

// Read the result
// All three possible desired results shown
const dataA = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'out.gif'); // Should be string
const dataS = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'out.gif', { encoding: 'binary' }); // Should be string
const dataU = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'out.gif', { encoding: 'utf8'); // Should be Uint8Array
```

The current code works, but `dataA`, `dataS`, and `dataU` are all of `string | Uint8Array` type.

Comment: Without a [mcve] that demonstrates what specifically is going wrong, it's hard to know what to tell you.  If I use your existing `FS` interface (and ignore everything afterward) it [looks fine to me](https://tsplay.dev/gWorpm).  But I don't understand what `FSMethodNames`, `FSMethodArgs`, and `FSMethodReturn` is supposed to be doing, and the line with `FS<Method extends FSMethodNames>` in it is just an error.  So, ‍♂️... could you modify the question to be specific about what the issue is?  Good luck!

Comment: Oh, are you intending the `FS` at the bottom to be a function?  Yeah, that will be tough... you want [higher order type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) but I don't know if there's any way to express what you're doing that way.

Comment: Yes, FS is a function. I am working on currently broken typings in the FFmpeg.wasm library. I have added a condensed example of the code I am currently using to test it.

Comment: Ugh, the support for higher order type inference only works if you actually call a function and actually pass a generic function as a callback to that function.  This makes it inapplicable to what you're trying to do.  You'll have to manually write out the type of your `FS` function, or at least the generic methods in it.  You can sort of strong-arm the compiler into calculating some of the types for you, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/qNBODm), but that's probably not worth it.   If you want I can write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried won't work because you need two generics, not one. `FS` would have to be generic over the `method` and over the `encoding`, but there is only one generic defined.

If you can accept a curried API, then you can use this instead:

```
declare function FS<Method extends FSMethodNames>(method: Method): FS[Method];

const string = FS('readFile')('index.js', { encoding: 'binary' });
const uintarray = FS('readFile')('index.js', { encoding: 'utf8' });
const either = FS('readFile')('index.js');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgYwPYBMCWcDmUC8UDkARhgIYBOI+UAPgQK7ABmAHPgNwBQoksiqGmACrhoeAN5RicciABcUAM7AyAgDRQGLeQFUMwZgEEyZEiCgBfThz0QyjEgmgAxAMpQxHKFDIQSKJ2gANhDyADyCUBAAHsAQcCgKvMjoWAB8ABRgJMAAFvJKKljqSGDACgD88hJxyQKVUILqjIEkmBX5ygIWAJS4qUn8WMKQANqCALqc5hxcIlCuALIQuagAciQAthCJ4lAjANJQGFAA1hAgSIzzLuPy6a7dB+ORMXEJUOkAdN-kbfIkcBAI3GvRw-QBZnKUEO8jgEAAbrYLCMzhcrq5JrMeItljlUEY2rh3HtDsccSsUOstgpblAAArkTbLWwKUKuJ79SxY5wuJYUgBKyzoZDgRIkByOovJeMpTJp8kFwGFcGGEDZLg5FisKAgCBaPigjDoiGAaCQUpcoT5MpesXiiWlazlGS2FPk1tQ3Xk7I9KExHGQcCUik6WCJrnS+B8fgCwXw3UjGB1UU+ACsFPh1NU+ClMPIiKQKFRzN1OIHg3Q9OQTGY8BGo75-EEIPHE-FommM1nIjmBPnNKwemXzcGIGhcki6y5I9Gm3GE-gkx30-G2EA)